# MATLAB : Get k random subscripts with condition from a Matrix

Tags: matlab, random, indexing

I'd like get `k` random subscripts from `A` to be used in a C++ program with currently load data from a file given a set of subscripts.

I've a `MxN` matrix `A` with double values and a `Mx1` matrix `B` with integers from 0 to 20.

How could i get `k` random subscripts from `A` with a condition from `B` ? In example, given:

```
A = [ 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25
      0.18 0.18 0.18 0.18 
      0.36 0.36 0.36 0.36 
      0.51 0.51 0.51 0.51 ]

B = [ 0 
      1
      2
      1 ]
```

I'm trying to get `k = 1` random row subscript `i` from `A` if `B(i) == 1`. So, I'm looking for `i == 1` or `i == 4`.

I've tried first create a logical index as:

```
idx = B == 1;
```

And then, get from `A` the elements with that condition as follow:

```
r = A( idx, : );
```

And finally, do a permutation in `r` to in order to get `k` rows:

```
randperm( size(r) )
```

But I'm stuck now as I do not know how to translate the permutation to the matrix `A`.

I'm also trying to understand the function `[I,J] = ind2sub(siz,IND)` but no idea right now how to join the subscripts with the randon permutation. Moreover, the results of `randperm( size(r) )` are related to the size of `r`.

So, How could i get `k` random subscripts from `A` with a condition from `B` ? The idea is use the subscripts in a C++ program as input parameters

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. It looks like you use `B` to select the rows of `A` you are interested in, but then what? Do you want a random element from those rows of `A`? Please try to explain some more.

Comment: @shoelzer The idea is use the subscripts in a C++ program as input parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the relevant row numbers as follows:

```
nrs=1:length(idx);
nrs=nrs(idx);
```

Now to permute them:

```
nrs_permidx = randperm(length(nrs))
permuted = nrs(nrs_permidx)
```

And I guess you can take it from here.